# Scipy: fill a histogram reading from a DB, event by event, in a loop

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

You sometimes don't want to fill a histogram *after* creating a huge list. You want to read a DB and fill the histogram event by event. Eg:

```
collection = db["my_collection"]
for event in collection.find():
   histogram.fill(event['a_number'])
```

So, if I have 10Bn entries in the collection, I can fill any histogram I need for analysis without putting all data in memory.

I have done this building my own fill_histogram function, but I think there ought be something ready to use... HBOOK FORTRAN library, developed in the 1980s, had "HFILL" as its most used subroutine ever:)

BTW, here is a function which does the job for numpy.histogram, but I could not find in numpy:

```
def hfill(histogram, datum, weight=1):
'''
Bin the right bin in a numpy histogram for datum, with weight.
If datum is outside histogram's bins' range, histogram does not change
'''
for idx, b in enumerate(histogram[1]):
    if idx > 0:
        if (datum < b and datum >= histogram[1][0]) or (datum <= b and idx == len(histogram[1]) - 1):
            histogram[0][idx - 1] += int(weight)
            break
```

Comment: not really an anwser, but you can always call Fortran Code from Python.

Comment: `collections.Counter`? http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Comment: @zhenya Counter is similar to histogram, but you must have a dict in memory. Then it counts the frequencies. No good then.

Comment: Not really, you can construct the Counter from any iterable. Try it with xrange (which does not pre-build anything). Am adding a simple example as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

I usually use a simple wrapper for the regular `numpy.histogram` that solves this problem:

```
import numpy as np

class Hist1D(object):

    def __init__(self, nbins, xlow, xhigh):
        self.nbins = nbins
        self.xlow  = xlow
        self.xhigh = xhigh
        self.hist, edges = np.histogram([], bins=nbins, range=(xlow, xhigh))
        self.bins = (edges[:-1] + edges[1:]) / 2.

    def fill(self, arr):
        hist, edges = np.histogram(arr, bins=self.nbins, range=(self.xlow, self.xhigh))
        self.hist += hist

    @property
    def data(self):
        return self.bins, self.hist
```

This allows the usage asked for:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

h = Hist1D(100, 0, 1)
for _ in range(1000):
    a = np.random.random((3,))
    h.fill(a)
    plt.step(*h.data)
    plt.show()
```

EDIT: In case someone has a similar event-based set-up, but for 2D data, I also have [code for that](https://github.com/NichtJens/numpy-accumulative-histograms). As it wasn't asked for in the question here, I didn't add it to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Even though this message was posted a while back, I thought I'd mention some useful tools, in the same vein as HBOOK/PAW, for what you're doing.  I've found no other good Python alternatives for dealing with huge out-of-memory data.

- PyROOT exposes the entire ROOT framework to Python, so you can use, for example, its TH1/2/3 and THnSparse variants (see http://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/pyroot and general ROOT documentation).  Under the assumption that you installed ROOT with python support and have some type of "events" (like ROOT's TTree/TChain, which is optimized for huge data sets), event-by-event filling would look something like this:

  ```
  from ROOT import TH1F
  nbins, lo, hi = 100, -3, 3
  hist = TH1F('hist', 'my hist', nbins, lo, hi)
  for evt in events:
      hist.Fill(evt.somevalue)
  # render the histogram on a TCanvas (active if present, new otherwise)
  hist.Draw()
  ```
- rootpy further "pythonizes" the ROOT interface (see http://rootpy.org).  Under the same assumption as above plus the assumption that rootpy is installed, only the first two lines of the above snippet would change to:

  ```
  from rootpy.plotting import Hist
  hist = Hist(nbins, lo, hi)
  ```

I've been using ROOT and PyROOT for a long time and recently tried rootpy for better integration with some SciPy tools.  rootpy's integration with matplotlib is also nice, especially if you want the histogram to show up in an IPython notebook, for example:

```
from rootpy.plotting import Hist
import rootpy.plotting.root2matplotlib as rplt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

hist = Hist(100, -3, 3)
hist.FillRandom('gaus')
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7, 5), dpi=100, facecolor='white')
rplt.errorbar(hist, xerr=False, emptybins=False)
plt.show()
```

The above snippet could serve as a minimal test to see if ROOt, PyROOT, rootpy, and matplotlib are installed.

Comment: We should conclude that numpy has no such a tool! Root is actually the main reason why I left HEP:), but rootpy seems to have a normal syntax, opposite to the original C++ "shell language".

Comment: @mennato I think you're correct. I was surprised that numpy doesn't seem to have such a concept. Regarding your solution, hfill... I wonder if it might be more efficient to find the bin with something like this:  int(bins*(x-minX)/(maxX-minX))

Comment: Root is a nightmare for people who are outside High Energy community.

Comment: Many years later again, this would be my go-to working locally, but for a particular project I need to do this in Google Colab which ROOT doesn't officially support, making it difficult to use these tools. I wish there was a straightforward numpy way of doing it!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simplified example:

```
>>> c = Counter()
>>> for j in xrange(10):
...   c[j] = j**2
>>> c
Counter({9: 81, 8: 64, 7: 49, 6: 36, 5: 25, 4: 16, 3: 9, 2: 4, 1: 1, 0: 0})
```

here at no time you have to have an in-memory list of integers. Sure, if you want to have the histogram as a `numpy` array, you'll have to construct it from the `Counter` manually.

If you're using python < 2.7, then `Counter` is not available from `collections`, but here's an [ActiveState recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576611/).

Comment: you can surely define bins --- as long as you can enumerate them: bin 0 is x<_0, bin 1 is x_0 < x < x_1, etc.